# Simple HTML parser- Foreach returns 14 rows instead of 7

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a html content like this...

```
  require('simple-parser.php');    
$html = <<<EOF
    <table  id="specialTbl">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td> row-1-td-1</td>
             <td> row-1-td-2</td>
             <td> row-1-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">  // Problem starts here
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-1-td-4-Child-1</td> 
                        <td>row-1-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-1-td-5</td>
             <td> row-1-td-6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td> row-2-td-1</td>
             <td> row-2-td-2</td>
             <td> row-2-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-2-td-4-Child-1</td>
                        <td>row-2-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-2-td-5</td>
             <td> row-2-td-6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td> row-3-td-1</td>
             <td> row-3-td-2</td>
             <td> row-3-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-3-td-4-Child-1</td>
                        <td>row-3-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-3-td-5</td>
             <td> row-3-td-6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td> row-4-td-1</td>
             <td> row-4-td-2</td>
             <td> row-4-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-4-td-4-Child-1</td>
                        <td>row-4-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-4-td-5</td>
             <td> row-4-td-6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td> row-5-td-1</td>
             <td> row-5-td-2</td>
             <td> row-5-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-5-td-4-Child-1</td>
                        <td>row-5-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-5-td-5</td>
             <td> row-5-td-6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td> row-6-td-1</td>
             <td> row-6-td-2</td>
             <td> row-6-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-6-td-4-Child-1</td>
                        <td>row-6-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-6-td-5</td>
             <td> row-6-td-6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td> row-7-td-1</td>
             <td> row-7-td-2</td>
             <td> row-7-td-3</td>
             <td>
                <table class="runsOn">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>row-7-td-4-Child-1</td>
                        <td>row-7-td-4-Child-2</td>               
                      </tr>               
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
             <td> row-7-td-5</td>
             <td> row-7-td-6</td>
          </tr>  
       </tbody>
    </table>
    EOF;
```

For each loop to generate a json

```
$html= str_get_html($html);
$table =$html->find('table#specialTbl',0) ; 
$response["response_code"] = 200;
$response["rows"]   = array();
foreach($table->find('tr') as $key=>$value) {
 $post["td1"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',0)->plaintext));
 $post["td2"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',1)->plaintext));
 $post["td3"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',2)->plaintext));
 $post["td4"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',3)->plaintext)); 
 $post["td5"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',4)->plaintext));
 $post["td6"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',5)->plaintext)); 
  array_push($response["rows"], $post);  
}
$json = json_encode($response);
echo $json_content;
```

And Json Response is

```
{
"response_code":200,
"rows":[
{
"td1":"row-1-td-1",
"td2":"row-1-td-2",
"td3":"row-1-td-3",
"td4":"row-1-td-4-Child-1 row-1-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-1-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-1-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-1-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-1-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
},
{
"td1":"row-2-td-1",
"td2":"row-2-td-2",
"td3":"row-2-td-3",
"td4":"row-2-td-4-Child-1 row-2-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-2-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-2-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-2-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-2-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
},
{
"td1":"row-3-td-1",
"td2":"row-3-td-2",
"td3":"row-3-td-3",
"td4":"row-3-td-4-Child-1 row-3-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-3-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-3-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-3-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-3-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
},
{
"td1":"row-4-td-1",
"td2":"row-4-td-2",
"td3":"row-4-td-3",
"td4":"row-4-td-4-Child-1 row-4-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-4-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-4-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-4-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-4-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
},
{
"td1":"row-5-td-1",
"td2":"row-5-td-2",
"td3":"row-5-td-3",
"td4":"row-5-td-4-Child-1 row-5-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-5-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-5-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-5-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-5-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
},
{
"td1":"row-6-td-1",
"td2":"row-6-td-2",
"td3":"row-6-td-3",
"td4":"row-6-td-4-Child-1 row-6-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-6-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-6-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-6-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-6-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
},
{
"td1":"row-7-td-1",
"td2":"row-7-td-2",
"td3":"row-7-td-3",
"td4":"row-7-td-4-Child-1 row-7-td-4-Child-2",
"td5":"row-7-td-4-Child-1",
"td6":"row-7-td-4-Child-2"
},
{
"td1":"row-7-td-4-Child-1",
"td2":"row-7-td-4-Child-2",
"td3":"",
"td4":"",
"td5":"",
"td6":""
}
]
}
```

Problem is with `foreach`. How can i skip the `tr` inside a `td`. I have 7 rows in table with id "specialTbl". But `for each` returns 14 rows in json as it loops through table called runsOn.

How can i avoid looping through table inside td(4th)..?

Comment: Try this. Remove `array_push($response["rows"], $post); ` from `foreach` loop and put it after `foreach`

Comment: You are right... Put the same in answer I will accept as answer and upvote it

Comment: @gunaseelan..... You are right... Put the same as answer I will accept as answer and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `array_push` outside `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($table->find('tr') as $key=>$value) {
 $post["td1"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',0)->plaintext));
 $post["td2"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',1)->plaintext));
 $post["td3"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',2)->plaintext));
 $post["td4"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',3)->plaintext)); 
 $post["td5"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',4)->plaintext));
 $post["td6"]= trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',5)->plaintext)); 
}

array_push($response["rows"], $post);
```